# How to Data Send from recyclerview to fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to send data from my recyclerview.
I have 24 object in my arraylist but I could see only 13 object on my onbindviewholder. And when I click on first item but it send last 13 object to other fragment.
How can I fix this?

Wall Adapter

```
public class WallAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WallViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener {
    private static ArrayList<Wallpaper> array1;


    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity;
    private MyListener myListener;
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    String sendPath, sendLargeUrl;

    public WallAdapter(AppCompatActivity appCompatActivity, MyListener myListener, ArrayList<Wallpaper> array1) {
        this.appCompatActivity = appCompatActivity;
        this.myListener = myListener;
        layoutInflater = appCompatActivity.getLayoutInflater();
        this.array1 = array1;


    }

    public static ArrayList<Wallpaper> getWallArray() {
        return array1;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public WallViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View listview = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.wall_row, parent, false);
        listview.setOnClickListener(this);
        return new WallViewHolder(listview);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull WallViewHolder holder, int position) {
        System.out.println(position + "pos on bind view holder");
        // holder.getWalls(appCompatActivity, array1.get(position));
        // sendLargeUrl = array1.get(position).getLargeUrl();
        holder.loadPicaso(appCompatActivity, array1.get(position));
        sendPath = array1.get(position).getWallID();

        sendLargeUrl = holder.getwLargeUrl(array1.get(position));




    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return array1.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        NavDirections action = WallFragmentDirections.actionWallFragmentToDetailFragment(sendPath, sendLargeUrl);


        Navigation.findNavController(v).navigate(action);


    }


    public interface MyListener {
        void MyListener(Wallpaper wallpaper);
    }

}
```

ViewHolder

```
public class WallViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    public WallViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        progressBar = itemView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    }
    public void loadPicaso (Context context, Wallpaper wallpaper) {
        itemView.setTag(wallpaper);

        Picasso.get().load(wallpaper.getLargeUrl()).into(imageView);
    }
```

Comment: Android RecycleView only render visible view, so 13 item can be visible and rendered

Comment: I think you are right.